# Unable to exec command into kubernetes pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

Python version 3.8.10
Kubernetes version 23.3.0

I'm trying to run a command into a specific pod in kubernetes using python. I've tried to reduce the code as much as I could, so I'm running this.

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
response = v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec(pod_name , namespace, command="df -h", stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=True)
print(response)
```

But it's not working. I'm getting this response.

```sh
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '511c23ce-03bb-4b52-a559-3f354fc80235', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Fri, 18 Mar 2022 18:06:11 GMT', 'Content-Length': '139'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Upgrade request required","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

If I run typical example of [list all pods](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) . It's working fine. So, it should not be a configuration issue. I've read about this problem in the past [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/58) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/409). But I assume it cannot be that, due to they are closed issues.

If I run k9s shell request, I can connect with pod with no problem. This is what I see in `ps a` when I'm doing this `/usr/bin/kubectl --context gke_cloudpak_europe-west2-xxxxx exec -it -n namespace_name pod_name -c rt -- sh -c command -v bash >/dev/null && exec bash || exec sh`

Another update, I've found this [info](https://kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html). At last of page there is a paragraph with says.

```
Why Exec/Attach calls doesn’t work
Starting from 4.0 release, we do not support directly calling exec or attach calls. you should use stream module to call them. so instead of resp = api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec(name, ... you should call resp = stream(api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, name, ....

Using Stream will overwrite the requests protocol in core_v1_api.CoreV1Api() This will cause a failure in non-exec/attach calls. If you reuse your api client object, you will need to recreate it between api calls that use stream and other api calls.
```

I've tried to do it in this way, but same result :(

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Regards

Comment: It's a common mistake; `command:` is **exec** style, not sh style, so what you want is `command: df, args: ["-h"]`

Comment: The previous comment seems valid, but I also get that particular error message when I try to exec a shell into a pod when I have any of the "proxy" vars set in the shell that I'm coming from. When I unset those vars, the exec succeeds.

Comment: Err, that's the first time anyone mentioned proxy -- for sure `exec` (and I believe `logs`, too) switch protocols so if you have a proxy between python and k8s that isn't websocket friendly, that will end poorly

Comment: Thanks for your helps @mdaniel. But it's not that. If I add ```args```, it's not recognized by method. And If I just set commando to ```df``` I get same response .

Comment: Could you please clarify that a little bit more @DavidM.Karr? I've not set anything on purpose, but  you never know. As I said, I can list all pods in cluster with no problems. And also using k9s, I can run remote shells, but at the end, this is using ```kubectl``` with some arguments ```docker``` style.

Comment: Before running the "kubectl" command line to exec into the container, do "env | grep -i proxy". If you have variations of "http(s)_proxy" or "no_proxy", try unsetting them and running the kubectl command again.

Comment: Nothing related with proxy in my env variables. @DavidM.Karr. Thanks for your idea, but it must me other issue... ```/usr/bin/kubectl --context gke_cloudpak_europe-west2-xxxxx exec -it -n namespace_name pod_name -c rt -- sh -c command -v bash >/dev/null && exec bash || exec sh```  This is what k9s runs to connect pod using shell, and works fine.

Comment: I have more info, I've found this ```Why Exec/Attach calls doesn’t work
Starting from 4.0 release, we do not support directly calling exec or attach calls. you should use stream module to call them. so instead of resp = api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec(name, ... you should call resp = stream(api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, name, ....

Using Stream will overwrite the requests protocol in core_v1_api.CoreV1Api() This will cause a failure in non-exec/attach calls. If you reuse your api client object, you will need to recreate it between api calls that use stream and other api calls.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this [official guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#why-execattach-calls-doesnt-work) says that you should use `resp = **stream**(api.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec(name, ...` instead.

So you have to edit your code like this:

```
...
from kubernetes.stream import stream
...
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
response = stream(v1.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, pod_name , namespace, command="df -h", stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=True)
print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks @Bazhikov. I had solved it before reading your response. It's exactly that. I had tried this, but I had just "added" ```connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec``` method into ```stream``` and it's not in that way, ``connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec``` has to be provided as first argument to ```stream```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to trying a different Python Kubernetes library this is [supported in `kr8s`](https://docs.kr8s.org/en/stable/examples/pod_operations.html#exec-a-command) without needing to worry about the details of the underlying HTTP transport.

```py
from kr8s.objects import Pod
response = Pod.get(pod_name, namespace).exec(["df", "-h"])
print(response.stdout.decode())
```